# Can't differentiate between colon and semicolon with VirtualKey

Tags: c#, enums, windows-phone-8.1, virtual-keyboard

I have a KeyDown handler on a TextBox in my Windows Phone 8.1 app, with a switch statement based on what key is pressed.

```
private void TextKeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case (VirtualKey)186: //semicolon is typed
            {
                DoStuffHere();
            }
        //other cases...
    }
}
```

I can't differentiate between colon and semicolon. I tried e.Key.ToString(), but I only get the enum number (186). Anyway to figure out exactly what character is being typed without looking directly at the text? Since this is a KeyDown event, I can't look at the text from here...

Comment: What character you get is based on the state of the modifier keys.  And the keyboard layout, it isn't the same between different languages.  Core problem is that you use the wrong event.  Use CharacterReceived instead.

Comment: Since it's a key, rather than text, event, all you know is which key was pressed - the ; and : are both accessed by pressing the same key, so fire the same event. You need to find a way of checking the shift state.